# Good questions and answers for a tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

No doubt all the questions and answers on Stack Overflow add value to our knowledge. But, still I think there should be something to see the questions or answers in a particular tag which have got these badges:

1. Favorite Question
2. Famous Question
3. Good Answer
4. Good Question
5. Great Question
6. Great Answer
7. Nice Answer
8. Nice Question
9. Notable Question
10. Popular Question

These may produce deterministic overhead in site-performance IMHO, so some of these could be more helpful. I know we can go to the badge and view for which question that is for , but still this will give direct access to those questions or answers **per tag**.

These questions and their answers could form an online library for the interested ones.

Comment: Users get badges, not question/answers.

Comment: @Oded Yeah..I am saying that we can have separate pages for good answers and questions like you have a page for users, sorted according to reputation.

Comment: @Oded And those questions and answers according to the tag..so I can view the questions for my favorite tag only.

Comment: @BhushanFirake - Are you saying that you want to browse questions/answers with particular tag[s] which is got such badges? E.g. List Good Questions tagged `[SQL]`.

Comment: @hims056 yeah..absolutely,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Mostly*** you can achieve that by our great [search option](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

1. Favorite Question - this is not available :(
2. [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views:10000)
3. [Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20score:25)
4. [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question%20score:25)
5. [Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question%20score:100)
6. [Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20score:100)
7. [Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20score:10)
8. [Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question%20score:10)
9. [Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question%20views:2500)
10. [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question%20views:1000)

Here you can add tag[s] in the search box like [Famous question tagged SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views:10000%20%5Bsql%5D)

Comment: Was it documented somewhere in FAQ?

Comment: @BhushanFirake - We have a [Search Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/search). See *Advanced Search Tips* there

Comment: OK thank you for this..

Comment: Tip of the hat for the effort in this answer.